# Is it possible to use AWS WAF to block users behind a NAT

Tags: amazon-waf, aws-nat-gateway

I am trying to place AWS WAF behind a NAT gateway to block some specific users. The image below explains exactly what I want to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does the NAT preserve client IP in XFF header? If yes, it might be possible: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/support-x-forwarded-for-header-available-aws-waf/

Otherwise, is there like session ID or unique ID you can use to block? Given that traffic coming from NAT, you won't be able to use block by source IP